# Jquery - more than one div will not show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, Im having a problem calling `.show()` on more than one div that is hidden to begin with. Ive gone through my logic but I can't find why it is doing this -

Each lab div looks like this but with a different class-

```
<div class="lab1">
    <!--CTedit -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><span style="margin-left: 12px; display: inline-block;"></span>Lab Focus: Cloud Management with vRealize Operations & <nobr>vRealize Automation</nobr></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span style="font-family:'proximanova-light', sans-serif;font-size:15px; line-height:19px; text-align:left; color: #565656;">
                    <p>Deliver intelligent operations management across physical, virtual, and cloud infrastructures and accelerate the deployment and management of applications and compute services, improving business agility and operational efficiency.</p>
                    <p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Build dashboards, views, and reports in vRealize Operations Manager</li>
                            <li>Discover OS  and application management with vRealize Operations Manager</li>
                            <li>Learn how vRealize Log Insight delivers real-time log management, with machine learning-based Intelligent Grouping, high performance search and better troubleshooting across physical, virtual, and cloud environments</li>
                            <li>Walk through the deployment of a multi-tier infrastructure workload with integrations into several different existing technologies using vRealize Automation</li>
                            <li>Customize workloads with vRealize Automation as they progress through the provisioning or de-provisioning process</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>
            <a class="l1Link" style="color:#6db33f;" href="http://vmware-events.eventbrite.com" target="_blank">
                <span style="text-align:center"><strong>&raquo; Register now</strong></span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="descP1" style="font-size:12px;"><strong>DAY DATE <br>VENUE <br> CITY STATE</strong> </p>
    </div>   <!--CTedit -->
</div>
```

I have a series of 8 divs that I hide initially here and I show all of them in a function that is called if a certain dropdown option is selected:

```
//setup
$(".lab1").hide();
$(".lab2").hide();
$(".lab3").hide();
$(".lab4").hide();
$(".lab5").hide();
$(".lab6").hide();
$(".lab7").hide();
$(".lab8").hide();

function init() {
    $(".lab1").show();
    $(".lab2").show();
    $(".lab3").show();
    $(".lab4").show();
    $(".lab5").show();
    $(".lab6").show();
    $(".lab7").show();
    $(".lab8").show();
});
```

So they start out hidden. When a dropdown form changes I call the following, which finds several matching results (for example, 1 option may trigger 3 of these lab divs) and SHOULD show all of them:

```
 //dropdown change
$(".form-control").change(function () {
    $(".lab1").hide();
    $(".lab2").hide();
    $(".lab3").hide();
    $(".lab4").hide();
    $(".lab5").hide();
    $(".lab6").hide();
    $(".lab7").hide();
    $(".lab8").hide();

    console.log(this.value);
    //find all matching events and get nums
    if (this.value == "All labs") {
        init();
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfEvents.length; i++) {
            if (arrayOfEvents[i][0] == this.value) {
                var chosen = arrayOfEvents[i][3];
                var newLink = arrayOfEvents[i][8];
                console.log("match!", chosen);

                var selectedLab = labArr[chosen - 1];
                displayLab(selectedLab, newLink);
                updateTxt(selectedLab, i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

displayLab shows the corresponding lab div, and I know this works because multiple matches are printed to console (2 matches here)-

[image]
However my problem is only 1 corresponding div, the first, is shown. All the others remain hidden. If I don't call the initial hiding of all of them in the form change func, multiple labs are displayed/expanded no problem.

Because I hide all the lab divs BEFORE I call displayLab on the right ones, I don't know why it won't unhide all the divs. Why is this happening? How can 
I fix this?

Comment: show your html part please,

Comment: Just did - look above

Comment: breifly what you want is to show  only the `li` elements in selected `div`, is that what you want.

Comment: No - I have 8 divs with 8 different selectors and I need to only show a couple, however Im only able to show one

Comment: in your html where arethe elements lab1, lab2???

Comment: Ask the behavior you want maybe someone tell you the best approach you can achieve the same behavior with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some elements to be initially hidden then show them according to an event by jQuery so hide them through inline css this is the best don't do it programmatically at application startup.

```
<div class="div1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="div2" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="divN" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Show them when an event triggered:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('.div1, .div2, .divN').show();
});
```

To show all hidden divs in a page at once:

```
// You can use this selector as a nested one 
// so all the hidden elements inside a 
// specific parent element will be selected.
$('div:hidden').show();
```

Try this for showing all the elements of the same `your-divs` class:

```
// This is not a recommended approach
$('.your-divs').each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Different classes can be selected by a group selector:

```
$('.class1, class2, .classN').show();
```

Comment: Where? I don't think that will work - I have multiple matching divs with different class selctors

Comment: Check answer update for different or multiple classes: `$('.class1, .class2, .classN').show();`.

Comment: No but look at my code - I get the classes that need to be shown with a for loop, so each one should be shown individually. Should I store the matching classes in an array or..?

Comment: Yes that is great to store it in an array

Comment: How would I hide all the divs that don't match ANY elements of my array?

Comment: You can use parent > child selectors, multiple/group selectors or you can give them all a new class for easy selection.

Comment: How would I show an array of classes? Like I now have an array of the selected div classes, but to show all of them I need to get the individual elements like 'class1, class2, class3'